# Adding dependencies to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, dependency-management

I want to use Choco 3.3.1 in my eclipse project. I added the needed jar file to the java build path. But in the readme file it says that I also need to add the required dependencies. They look like this:

```
org.javabits.jgrapht:jgrapht-core:jar:0.9.3
dk.brics.automaton:automaton:jar:1.11-8
args4j:args4j:jar:2.32
net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:jar:3.0.3
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.13
```

Where can I add those without maven, gradle etc.?
(The project is a scala project, but I don't think that's the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to locate and download them from the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/). You can search by artifact and/or group ID and locate the exact version(s) you're looking for. For example, here's the [search for the `jgrapht`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22jgrapht-core%22) JAR.

Having said that, why not use Gradle, which has [Scala support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html)? Or [sbt, the Scala build tool](http://www.scala-sbt.org/)? You should at least give those some consideration.